# some aspx pages throw "[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]" error on loading from windows host

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

my website involved two section : Client and Admin, after I test whole site on localhost on my system to ensure the integrity of my site, upload it on windows host. 
The Client section is ok and all of pages loaded correctly. but the admin section have a very strange problem. after I login from my login.aspx page I can just only reach one of all my pages from my admin menu or direct URL, otherwise the server throw this error :

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   The network path was not found
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>   Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found
>   Source Error:
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>   Stack Trace:
>   [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]

but I'm sure the aspx file is exist on my host and the address is correct, What happened here is that the problem can be addressed server is disrupted?

To clarify my goal, put the code corresponding to the desired page.
[image: Location of web Files]
[image: Location of Admin folder Files]

the code of an aspx page that load correctly

> http://www.khanehayeroyaei.com/Admin/insertGalleryManager.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin/MasterPage.master" 

AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="insertGalleryManager.aspx.cs" Inherits="gallery" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor" TagPrefix="cc2" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="sideMap" Runat="Server">
    <div class="path">
        <div id="date_time">
            <%=userAdmin %>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <% DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"); %>

        </div>
        <div id="pathu">
            <asp:Button ID="btnExit" runat="server" Text="exit" OnClick="btnExitManager_Click" CssClass="btnExit"/>
            <strong><a href="changepassword.aspx">change password</a> </strong>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Menu" runat="server">
    <ul id="nav" class="dropdown dropdown-vertical dropdown-vertical-rtl">
        <li><img style="float:right;margin:10px 10px 0px 8px;" src="../imagesAdmin/post.png" /><span class="dir">project managment</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="insertProjectAdmin.aspx">Insert Images</a></li>
                <li><a href="EditDelProject.aspx">Edit and Remove</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><img style="float:right;margin:10px 10px 0px 8px;" src="../imagesAdmin/backgroung.png" /><span class="dir">Gallery Managment</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="insertGalleryManager.aspx">Insert New Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="EditDelGalleryManager.aspx">Edit and Remove Gallery</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><img style="float:right;margin:10px 10px 0px 8px;" src="../imagesAdmin/gallery.png" /><span class="dir">Image Managment</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="insertBackgroungImages.aspx">Insert Background</a></li>
                <li><a href="EditDelBackgroundImages.aspx"> Remove</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><img style="float:right;margin:10px 10px 0px 8px;" src="../imagesAdmin/admin.png" /><span class="dir">Admin Managment</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="insertManager.aspx">new Admin</a></li>
                <li><a href="EditDelManager.aspx">Edit Admin</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><img style="float:right;margin:10px 10px 0px 8px;" src="../imagesAdmin/email.png" /><span class="dir"><a href="contact.aspx">Emails</a></span>  
        </li> 
    </ul>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="MessageError" Runat="Server">
    <div style="margin-top:250px;text-align:center;float:right;width:400px;">
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="leftContent">
    <div class="left_post">
        <div style="border:solid 1px #b4cbdf;height:530px;margin-bottom:10px;">
                    <div class="left" style="margin-top:-32px;">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListCategory" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" AutoPostBack="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListCategory_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="170px" style="margin-right:55px;">
                        </asp:DropDownList><br/>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtImgTitle" runat="server" style="margin-right:55px;margin-top:25px;font-size:10px;width:170px;height:30px;padding:0px;"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFileName" runat="server" Text="..." style="float:right;margin-top:90px;margin-right:-90px;margin-bottom:-20px;"></asp:Label><br /><br /><br />
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="UploadPicture" runat="server" CssClass="up_load" style="margin-right:-10px;float:right;margin-top:60px;margin-left:100px;"/><br/><br/>
                        <asp:Button ID="btn_UploadPicture" runat="server" Text="Upload" CssClass="btnUpload" OnClick="btn_UploadPicture_Click" />
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" CssClass="imgPreview"/>
                    </div>
             </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left_post">
        <div style="border:solid 1px #b4cbdf;height:440px;margin-bottom:10px;">
                <div class="left" style="margin-top:-32px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFileNameSmall" runat="server" Text="..." style="float:right;margin-right:50px;margin-top:28px;"></asp:Label><br /><br /><br />
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="UploadPictureSmall" runat="server" CssClass="up_load" style="margin-right:-60px;float:right;margin-top:10px;"/><br/><br/><br/>
                        <asp:Button ID="btn_UploadPictureSmall" runat="server" Text="Thumbnail Upload" CssClass="btnUpload" OnClick="btn_UploadPictureSmall_Click" style="margin-top:-65px;" />
                    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" CssClass="imgPreviewSmall"/>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_InsertPicture" runat="server" Text="Apply" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btn_InsertPicture_Click" />
                </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

the code of an aspx page that doesn't load correctly

http://khanehayeroyaei.com/Admin/insertManager.aspx

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="insertManager.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin_insertManager" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<title>InsertManager</title>
        .btnExit
        {   
            font-family:B Nazanin;
            font-size:14px;
            color:#000;width:150px;height:25px;
            float:left;margin-left:10px;
        }
        .btnApply
        {
            float:right;
            width: 150px;
            height:30px;
            margin:-39px -30px 0px 90px;
            padding:0 5px 5px 5px;
            font-family:'B Nazanin';
            font-size:16px;
        }
        .validator {
            font-size:12px;
            color:red;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-align:right;
            float:right;
            margin-right:5px;
            padding-top:8px;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="sideMap" Runat="Server">
    <div class="path">
        <div id="date_time">
            <%=userAdmin %>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <% DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"); %>
        </div>
        <div id="pathu">
            <asp:Button ID="btnExit" runat="server" Text="Exit" OnClick="btnExitManager_Click" CssClass="btnExit"/>
            <strong><a href="changepassword.aspx">Change password</a> </strong>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Menu" Runat="Server">
    <ul id="nav" class="dropdown dropdown-vertical dropdown-vertical-rtl">
        <li><img style="float:right;margin:10px 10px 0px 8px;" src="../imagesAdmin/post.png" /><span class="dir">مدیریت پروژه ها</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="insertProjectAdmin.aspx">Insert Project Image</a></li>
                <li><a href="EditDelProject.aspx">Edit and Remove</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><img style="float:right;margin:10px 10px 0px 8px;" src="../imagesAdmin/backgroung.png" /><span class="dir">مدیریت گالری</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="insertGalleryManager.aspx">New Galley</a></li>
                <li><a href="EditDelGalleryManager.aspx">Edit and Remove</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><img style="float:right;margin:10px 10px 0px 8px;" src="../imagesAdmin/gallery.png" /><span class="dir">مدیریت عکس</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="insertBackgroungImages.aspx">New Background</a></li>
                <li><a href="EditDelBackgroundImages.aspx">Edit and Remove</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><img style="float:right;margin:10px 10px 0px 8px;" src="../imagesAdmin/admin.png" /><span class="dir">مدیران</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="insertManager.aspx">New Admin</a></li>
                <li><a href="EditDelManager.aspx">Edit and Remove</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><img style="float:right;margin:10px 10px 0px 8px;" src="../imagesAdmin/email.png" /><span class="dir"><a href="contact.aspx">Emails</a></span>  
        </li> 
    </ul>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="MessageError" Runat="Server">
    <div style="margin-top:250px;text-align:center;float:right;width:400px;">
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="leftContent" Runat="Server">
    <div class="left_post" style="float:right;text-align:right;margin-bottom:20px;">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="Username" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
            AllowSorting="True" 
            AllowPaging="True"
            ForeColor="Black" 
            GridLines="Vertical"
            BackColor="White"
            BorderColor="#DEDFDE" 
            BorderStyle="None"
            BorderWidth="1px" 
            CellPadding="4"
            Width="100%">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Username">
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#3366CC" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="password" SortExpression="Password">
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#3366CC" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FName" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="FName" >
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#3366CC" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LName" HeaderText="last name" SortExpression="LName">
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#3366CC" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                </asp:BoundField>
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:khanehayeRoyaeiConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Username], [Password], [FName], [LName] FROM [Login]" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Login] ([Username], [Password], [FName], [LName]) VALUES (@Username, @Password, @FName, @LName)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Login] SET [Username] = @Username, [Password] = @Password, [FName] = @FName, [LName] = @LName" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Login] WHERE [Username] = @Username">
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LName" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
        <div class="left_post" style="float:right;text-align:right;margin-bottom:20px;">
            <div class="post" style="margin-top:20px;height:280px;">
                <div class="label_right">
                    <asp:Label ID="Username" runat="server" Text="username:"></asp:Label><br /><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Password" runat="server" Text="password:"></asp:Label><br /><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="FName" runat="server" Text="name:"></asp:Label><br /><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="LName" runat="server" Text="last name:"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="txtBox_left">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUsername"  CssClass="validator" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                           <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" MaxLength="20" TextMode="password"/>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword"  CssClass="validator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtfName" runat="server" MaxLength="20"/>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtfName"  CssClass="validator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtlName" runat="server" MaxLength="20"/><br />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtlName"  CssClass="validator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                    <asp:Button ID="btnApply" runat="server" Text="Apply" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btnApply_Click" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</asp:Content>
```

The Error on insertManager.aspx
[image: Error Image]

Comment: What are you doing *inside* that page? Loading a file from a network location perhaps?

Comment: clearly there is a problem with your code. you need to figure out if the user account the website is using on the apppool has access to the network folder in question.

Comment: The stack trace seems to be missing but most likely your code is calling something that tries to access a netwok location that does not exist. The stack trace should provide information of what part of your code that initiates the call. Interestingly the error code (0x80004005) is E_FAIL which is a rather general error and not a specific network error.

Comment: Patrick Hofman- Yes I Do , Load it from a host

Comment: the error is related to sql server

Comment: -qamar - How do you think ? please explain me . I try all of my website on local host without any error